# Adding nested attribute associations on checkbox click using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms

I'm new to rails but getting a pretty good handle on it, but my javascript/jquery knowledge is virtually nil. I have watched Ryan Bates' Railscast on building complex forms, but I'm looking for a slightly more up-to-date, less obtrusive solution to my problem.

Essentially I have a sample batch creation form, and I would like it to accept nested attributes for a has_many :through association to a series of tests (assays) that can be performed on the batch. It makes the most sense to list these assays as a series of checkboxes. It does not make sense to initialize the form with `assays.count` many associations because on submission there would almost certainly be several nil associations created along with the desired associations (If I am wrong on this, feel free to set me straight, I'm a blank slate). Consequently, it makes the most sense to me that I should be creating/destroying new association instance upon click/unclick of the checkboxes, but I'm new enough to not be sure exactly how to approach this with rails and jquery/javascript.

I'm not looking for big honking chunk of code where you do my work for me, I'd be more than happy with a few links to some current guides on similar subjects as my searches have been fruitless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize the form with `assays.count` objects because you can easily get rid of blank ones thanks to `reject_if`:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, :reject_if => lambda { |c| c[:title].blank? }
```

If you want to find alternatives, check there: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Ok it's obstrusive js but in the comments someone provides an unobstrusive solution

Comment: Thanks, I ran into that just earlier this afternoon. Can't believe I completely missed it. Thanks for the tip!